# How to start Google Chrome in the background before signing in?

Tags: chrome, mx-linux

I am trying to start chrome in the background before I login like this:

/etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#

su --login juan /home/juan/bin/scripts/initChrome.sh
exit 0
```

This is the sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window;
```

For some reason it doesn't start. I did the tests to see what happened and I get this error:

```
root@JuanDavid:/home/juan# su --login juan /home/juan/bin/scripts/initChrome.sh
[1108/125347.857986:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/8a03449b-2ed2-4f12-bdd0-97a08ee7791d.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.858034:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/3660d16c-2f07-4ad1-8589-452fe1bc22ba.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.858044:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/df78db7b-7e60-4493-b7a4-66edee2faf8d.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.858072:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/a8af800b-6c31-4865-aae0-56aebb913c1f.lock: File exists (17)
[33595:33595:1108/125347.903116:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[33595:33595:1108/125347.903152:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[1108/125347.972651:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/8a03449b-2ed2-4f12-bdd0-97a08ee7791d.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.972696:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/3660d16c-2f07-4ad1-8589-452fe1bc22ba.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.972706:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/df78db7b-7e60-4493-b7a4-66edee2faf8d.lock: File exists (17)
[1108/125347.972730:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/juan/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/a8af800b-6c31-4865-aae0-56aebb913c1f.lock: File exists (17)
[33626:33626:1108/125348.017772:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[33626:33626:1108/125348.017810:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

dice que el error se debe a que:

> ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY

If I start chrome background when I log in I have to wait for chrome to load and that is what I want to avoid.

I'm aiming for Chrome to open instantly the first time on Linux like it does on Windows.

Comment: you have three conflicting tags: [tag:ubuntu], [tag:linux-mint] and [tag:mx-linux] (and any of these three makes the [tag:linux] tag a bit redundant). Am I right in guessing this is actually MX Linux?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think prestarting will work this way; it's interesting that chrome takes longer to start on your Linux than on your windows, considering it shouldn't. (and I don't think Chrome on Windows would preload, either. That's generally undesirable.). My bet is what it's waiting for is for services to become ready – but that's actually hard to debug, and would depend on the Linux distro you're actually using, possibly :)

Comment: No X server runs when the `/etc/rc.local` script executes.

Comment: hmm there is no alternative to /etc/rc.local to run it before login? Actually it already achieved my purpose: Chrome opens instantly by starting it in the background; I just have to start it before login and after login for it to work. I would like to run it only once, that is, before logging in.

Comment: sorry for the bunch of tags. I thought the tags would attract the attention of all linux users. I think this question has been unanswered for a long time. Every user wants the best performance and this is a problem in almost all Linux distributions.

Comment: There are ways to automatically log you in, and to run a program when you log in, but I'm not aware of a way to get a program that needs X like Chrome to run before you actually log in to X. There is a headless option but I don't think that does what you're looking for.

Comment: Can confirm that what the script does does not actually reduce my chrome start time.

Comment: Marcus Müller
I found it testing in mxlinux21, it was based on debian11 and with a cinnamon desktop environment and I tell you that it opens faster than in windows the first time I open it.

Comment: The key is to run it from /etc/rc.local because although it doesn't start completely due to the lack of an X server, it does start some libraries and services. Then you also need to start it after login. In my case I only have to search for "applications at startup" and add where it says command "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window" with delay at startup of 0sec. In the case of kde, you only have to search for autorun and there you can configure the order.